# Weird opencv compilation error

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

So all I am trying to do is compile my program with opencv-2.3 . This is all under the assumtion that I installed everything correctly.

My Main is super simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
int main(int argv, char** argc){
   std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

My MakeFile is super simple.

```
g++ main.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

And the error is really confusing:

```
 make
g++ main.cpp \
`pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:62:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:56,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64,
             from main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:358:41: error: macro "max" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:369:41: error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:62:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:56,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64,
             from main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:354:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:354:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:354:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:354:5: error: expected initializer before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:358:5: error: template declaration of ‘const _Tp& std::max’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:365:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:365:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:365:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:365:5: error: expected initializer before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/algorithmfwd.h:369:5: error: template declaration of ‘const _Tp& std::min’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/algorithm:63:0,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:56,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64,
             from main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘void std::__merge_sort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator1, _RandomAccessIterator1, _RandomAccessIterator2, _Distance)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:3285:26: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘void std::__merge_sort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator1, _RandomAccessIterator1, _RandomAccessIterator2, _Distance, _Compare)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:3308:26: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:59:0,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64,
             from main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex: In function ‘_Tp std::__complex_abs(const std::complex<_Tp>&)’:`
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:571:28: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/vector:65:0,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:63,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64,
             from main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h: In member function ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_check_len(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const char*) const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1244:40: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/vector:66:0,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:63,
             from /usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64,
             from main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h: In member function ‘std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::size_type std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::_M_check_len(std::vector<bool, _Alloc>::size_type, const char*) const’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_bvector.h:1026:45: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
```

Now when I hit pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv in the terminal I get the correct place where all the libs and the .hpp and other files. So I have no idea what is going on here.
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: why use 2.3, when you can have 2.4.9 ?

Comment: @berak because of how older code extracts features. Needs to be the same version as the legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by using the old, C headers. The new ones are located in `<opencv2/opencv.hpp>` if I remember correctly.